# What does declaring default parameters in a function do under the hood?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

This is not a debugging question or a how-to question. This is a conceptual question.

I was finding it hard to wrap my head around what [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#scope_effects) "second scope" thing is, but overlooking the details I came up with this explanation:

If a function is stored (in some way) like this:

```js
{
  // function body written using undefined parameters. 
  // When the function is called the arguments are assigned to the parameters.
}
```

Declaring default parameters does this:

```js
{ // Second scope
  parameter1 = "something"
  parameter2 = 5
  {
    // function body written using the above parameters. 
    // When the function is called the arguments or default values get assigned to the parameters.
  }
}
```

Is this what really happens under the hood? If not, then what happens in there? The [ECMAScript docs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) are *way* above my level. Maybe someone could provide the explanation in layman's terms? Thanks!

Comment: Just one nitpick: *"When the function is called the arguments take the place of parameters"* The arguments don't take the place of the parameters, the *values* of the arguments are *assigned* to the parameters. If you have `function example(a) { /*...*/ }` and you do `let b = 42; example(b)`, the `a` parameter gets its value in exactly the same way that `a = b` would have given it its value. There's no ongoing connection between the source of the argument value (`b`) and the parameter. That's almost certainly what you meant, but... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty good explanation! Yes, the parameter list has its own scope. Let me expand on your explanation a bit and then explain why the additional scope there.

When you call a function without default parameter values, a new scope is created for the body of the function, and the parameters are created in that scope like top-level variables in the function. So, conceptually:

```
<<
    let param1 = /*...the argument value provided for param 1 if any */;
    let param2 = /*...the argument value provided for param 2 if any */;

    // Start of function code
    var variable1;
    let variable2;
    // End of function code
>>
```

(I'm using `<<`/`>>` delimiters instead of `{`/`}` because the scopes aren't just block scopes, they isolate `var` as well; so I picked an arbitrary delimiter.)

When there are default parameter values, as you've described, there's an additional scope involved:

```
<<
    let param1 = /*...the argument value provided for param 1 if any */;
    let param2 = /*...the argument value provided for param 2 if any */;
    <<
        // Start of function code
        var variable1;
        let variable2;
        // End of function code
    >>
>>
```

The reason is that default parameter values are *expressions*, not just literals. For example:

```js
function example(a = 1, b = a + 1) {
//                          ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−− expression, not just literal
    return a + b;
}

console.log(example());  // 1 + (1 + 1) = 3
console.log(example(2)); // 2 + (2 + 1) = 5
```

One reason that matters is that if there were just one scope for the parameter list and the function body, that would mean an expression in the parameter list could refer to hoisted variables and functions declared in the function body. The hoisted variables would just have the value `undefined`, so that wouldn't have been useful, but the hoisted functions would be initialized with their function bodies, leading to a situation like this:

```
// Doesn't work because of the additional scope
function example(a, b = blarg()) {
    function blarg() {
        return 42;
    }
    // ...
}
```

That causes a ReferenceError because the function body's scope isn't available in the parameter list's scope.

IIRC there were arguments for and against and a fair bit of discussion, but in the end the decision was to put the parameter list in its own scope to prevent that and other oddities.

Comment: FWIW, I go into this in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 3 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile.

Comment: Is this why one can use something like `function greet(name, greeting, message = greeting + ' ' + name)` here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#earlier_parameters_are_available_to_later_default_parameters because JavaScript reads the parameters from left to right and starts setting `param1 = "something"` then `param2 = "something else"` one after another so we can just use these 2 parameters in the third parameter?

Comment: @BookOfFlames - The additional scope isn't the reason for that, but yes, exactly, they're handled in source code order, so later parameters can refer to earlier parameters, but earlier parameters can't refer to later ones because those aren't initialized yet. Just like `let name = arg0; let greeting = arg1; let message = arg2 ?? greeting + ' ' + name;` (except `??` would take the right-hand for `null`, too, but default parameters only take the value specifically if the arg is `undefined`).