# Do default parameters need to be in useCallback dependency array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The title is explanatory enough, here is an example of such a case:

```
const handleDateChange = useCallback((startDate = defaultStartDate, endDate = defaultEndDate) => {
      // Do something
}, [defaultStartDate, defaultEndDate]);
```

Do `defaultStartDate` and `defaultEndDate` need to be included in the dependency array (like in my example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because they're referenced by the function, so the previous version of the function referencing the old values cannot be reused when the values change. It's just like using those variables in the function body.

Your `handleDateChange` is *effectively*¹ the same as this, which makes it more obvious why you need those defaults in the dependency array:

```
const handleDateChange = useCallback(
    (startDate, endDate) => {
        if (startDate === undefined) {
            startDate = defaultStartDate;
        }
        if (endDate === undefined) {
            endDate = defaultEndDate;
        }
        // Do something
    },
    [defaultStartDate, defaultEndDate]
);
```

---

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75132134/react-do-default-parameters-need-to-be-in-usecallback-dependency-array/75132160?noredirect=1#comment132583625_75132160), you've asked:

> In your code snippet you reassign the parameter in de body, in my example i do it in the parameters. Doesn't reassigning have different behaviour? Just like how Nullish coalescing (??) for example is different in this case?

No, the above is how default parameter values work. They're evaluated (if needed) during the call to the function, not (for instance) when the function is created. The JavaScript engine inserts code at the very beginning of your function (in a wrapper scope; [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428943/157247)) that does the `if` and assignment above. (It's very similar to nullish coalescing, but `null` doesn't trigger the default, only `undefined` does, as in the code above). Here's an example:

```js
function alloc() {
    const value = Math.random();
    console.log(`alloc called, returning ${value}`);
    return value;
}

function example(p = alloc()) {
    console.log(`p = ${p}`);
}

console.log("Call with a value other than `undefined` (no call to `alloc`):");
example(42);
console.log();

console.log("Call without a value (calls `alloc`):");
example();
console.log();

console.log("Call with `undefined` (also calls `alloc`):");
example(undefined);
console.log();

console.log("Call with `null` (doesn't call `alloc`):");
example(null);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

¹ "effectively" — There are two minor differences:

1. the `length` property of your function using default parameter values is `0`, whereas it's `2` in my rewrite.
2. There's a wrapper scope involved that I haven't tried to replicate in this simple example (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428943/157247) for details). But the above is fundamentally how they work.*

FWIW, here's a small excerpt from the part of my book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev) where I explain the parameter scope:

[image: LISTING 3-3: Defaults can’t refer to things in the function body—default-access-body.js function example(value = x) { var x = 42; console.log(value); } example(); // ReferenceError: x is not defined I’ve used var there because it doesn’t have the Temporal Dead Zone; it’s hoisted to the top of the scope where it’s declared. But the default value expression still couldn’t use it. The reason is that defaults are evaluated in their own scope, which exists between the scope containing the function and the scope inside the function, see Figure 3-1. It’s as though the function were wrapped in another function that handled doing the defaults.]

Comment: In your code snippet you reassign the parameter in de body, in my example i do it in the parameters. Doesn't reassigning have different behaviour? Just like how Nullish coalescing (??) for example is different in this case?

Comment: @Mees - I've updated the answer to answer the question in your comment. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you add few words what you mean with "mini-scope" above?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava - I shouldn't have called it a "mini-scope" (though its actual contents are quite small in most cases). Using default parameter values creates a wrapper scope between the outer scope and the function scope. I describe it in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428943/157247) and in the *Defaults Are Evaluated In Their Own Scope* section of Chapter 3 of [my book](https://thenewtoys.dev).